# Compiled successfully, but no console output

Tags: c, pthreads, openmp

I'm trying to use LLVM on windows.
I've installed llvm-mingw(https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/releases/tag/20220906), and it works like a charm.
Everything works well, but pthread and openmp.

Code compilation done with no errors, so I think there's no linking issue or something like that.
Notice that there's no compilation or linking error below, but no console out.

```
 PS C:\Users\first\Developments\Temp> clang -Wall -Wextra -fopenmp .\test.c
 PS C:\Users\first\Developments\Temp> ./a.exe
 PS C:\Users\first\Developments\Temp>
```

Where did I go wrong? Here's my c code and vscode configuration(cmd args).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void)
{
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        printf("%d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```json
"args": [
    "-O0",
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-fcolor-diagnostics",
    "-fansi-escape-codes",
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}\\.exe\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "-lm",
    "-lpthread",
    "-fopenmp"
],
```

Comment: According to those args, you're writing the output executable in a subfolder called `.exe`. So, whatever you're running, it's not the output of the build from that config. Cut/paste can often be as ruthless as it is helpful.

Comment: Other sources not using pthread or openmp are wroking correctly. And as you can see, even in command line it does not produce any output.

Comment: I would try adding an additional `printf` at the start of `main()` to verify that you're running the executable that you think you are. If you want to get fancy, include `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` in the print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of so called "Human Error". The computers never lies unless it deals with floating point decimals.

The problem was that I didn't setup the environment properly.
I did not add path of .dll files in PATH.

Now that I fixed them, it works like a charm!